# populating 1 column of rows that have values 0 using SQL window functions possibly with next max/prev min value of row index

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is one iteration of the test data:

```
DECLARE @trial TABLE (id int)

INSERT INTO @trial (id)
VALUES (0), (0),(3), (0), (0),(0), (7), (0),(9), (0), (0),(12), (0), (0),(15) 

select * from @trial
```

The numbers will always be a sequence of 0 or the row number. In any set if the number is not zero, the number will always represent the row so it will always be increasing.

I need the 0's to take on the next max value. So the output should be this:

```
3
3
3
7
7
7
7
9
9
12
12
12
15
15
15
```

please help!!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i am using sql 2016

Comment: @charliealpha . . . "I need the 0's to take on the next max/prev min value."  Your question is not clear.  How do you know which value you want?

Comment: it depends on the 1st row. if 1st row = 0, then take next max (if that makes sense). if 1st row <> 0, then take prev min. no change to be made to the row values <> 0.

Comment: Join to a row_number sequence generated against the values set

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean. can u give some more details @SteveC cheers.

Comment: Why does the first and second example have the same last 5 rows but different expected outcome?  Shouldn't example 1 end with 12, 12, 14, 14 the same way example 2 ends?

Comment: @SteveC thanks, ive simplified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
declare @trial table (id int)

insert into @trial (id)
values (0), (0),(3), (0), (0),(0), (7), (0),(9), (0), (0),(12), (0), (0),(15)  ;

;with
seq_cte as (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn from @trial),
break_cte as (select s.rn, isnull(t.id, 0)  input_n, iif(isnull(t.id, 0)=0, 0, 1) seq_break,
                     lag(iif(isnull(t.id, 0)=0, 0, 1), 1, 0) over (order by s.rn) seq_break_lag
              from seq_cte s left join @trial t on s.rn=t.id),
group_cte as (select *, sum(bc.seq_break_lag) over (order by bc.rn) break_grp from break_cte bc),
join_v_cte as (select id, (row_number() over (order by id))-1 jrn from @trial where id<>0)
select vc.id
from group_cte gc  
     join
     join_v_cte vc on gc.break_grp=vc.jrn;
```

Results

```
id
3
3
3
7
7
7
7
9
9
12
12
12
15
15
15
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering -- and no cumulative max -- unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

This is easy to include by having an `identity` column.  Such a column will preserve insertion order, which is apparently what you want.  So, this does what you want:

```
DECLARE @trial TABLE (id int identity, val int)

INSERT INTO @trial (val)
VALUES (1), (0),(0), (0), (0),(0), (7), (0),(9), (0), (0),(12), (0), (14),(0) 

select * from @trial

select max(val) over (order by id) as running_max
from @trial
order by id;
```

EDIT:

In your sample data, you want to look *forward* as well as *backward*.  For this, you can use a `case` expression to find the cases where the first rows have `0`:

```
select (case when max(val) over (order by id) = 0
             then min(case when val > 0 then val end) over (order by id desc)
             else max(val) over (order by id) 
        end) as running_max
from trial
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c53b3f4e115f2dcb9befce3f60a511a6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thanks. the iteration are a result of an ordered query. i will insert id's into the query & this should work! thanks!!

Comment: sorry spoke too soon. it didn't work for the 1st set of data. can u recheck? thanks.

Comment: 4th, 5th & 6th row turned out to be 3. they should be 7. thanks for your help. any ideas? cheers